# cloudinary authentication primer

Tags: javascript, cors, restful-authentication, cloudinary

I am trying to use the Cloudinary REST API, but the client libraries provided are not useful for my purpose.

So the settings I use are:

```
api_key = '111111111111111';
api_secret = 'fdgdsfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg';
my_authorization = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(this.api_key + ':' + this.api_secret);
url_base = 'http://api.cloudinary.com/api/v1_1';
cloud_name = '/http-mysite-com';
connect_method = 'GET';
tag_list = '/tags/image';
```

I make the call with something similar to this:

```
request(tag_list) {
    connection.request({
        method: connect_method, 
        url: url_base + cloud_name + service_url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': authorization,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
      // triumph
    }, function(er) {
      // all is lost
    });
};
```

The response is this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.cloudinary.com/api/v1_1/http-mysite-com/tags/image. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `'http://myhost:8000'` is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

PS I also tried using 'https' instead of 'http', as the documentation [recommends](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#protocol_and_authentication). In that case I get back:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/http-mysite-com/tags/image. The
>   request was redirected to
>   'http://api.cloudinary.com/api/v1_1/http-mysite-com/tags/image',
>   which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admin API calls use your `api_secret` which should not be revealed in your client-side code. That's why Cloudinary doesn't support CORS headers for the Admin API.
Therefore, Admin API calls should be performed on the server-side only.